# Redirect browser only if a web site is available

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer

I have an HTML file stored on the local file system.  I need it to redirect (or otherwise display in some fashion) a remote web site ONLY if the site is online and available.  If the site is not available, I need to display a user-friendly message.

Currently I have:

```
<html>
<body onload="window.location.href='http://someserver/';">
    <p>Connecting to remote server...</p>
</body>
</html>
```

The problem is that if the server is unavailable, the user is presented with an ugly "can't find server" page from the web browser.  I would rather display some custom HTML indicating the situation to the user if the page navigation is having trouble.  What are some commonly-used solutions I should try that would work well for this?

Requirement: must work in IE6 thru IE9.  FireFox/WebKit engines won't be used for this application.

Comment: You could do an XHR to the URL and see whether it succeeds.

Comment: When you say 'remote web site' I think that prevents JavaScript from working (due to the [same-origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy)). I think you'll need a server-side script (such as php, for example) to implement this.

Comment: The HTML file is stored in an executable file as a Windows resource.  Specificially, it is accessed using a URL like: res://mylibrary.dll/redirector.htm.  It's then hosted in a C++ program using the IE web browser control.  (I should add/apologize that I have not regularly done anything with HTML/JS for several years... - most of my work is in C++ these days)  I should hope/think that the res: protocol gets a fair bit of freedom from a security perspective, seeing as how this is the same protocol that IE uses internally for error pages, etc...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A simple way will be to try to load a known small image and you detect if the loading is done or not.

```
<img src="http://www.rgagnon.com/images/pdf.gif"
   onload="window.location='http://www.rgagnon.com';"
   onerror="window.location='http://www.google.com';"
>
```

If the pdf.gif is loaded, we switch to the site, if not we go somewhere else.

Answer (score 2):

You could use an AJAX style request on load to assure the server is alive before redirecting the browser to it, but there is no guarantee the server will *still be alive* when the redirection occurs.

Comment: That solution would still catch 99% of cases which is enough.  Most common case would be where the user is on a laptop that is not connected to the Internet, for example...